# What's the difference between the two TSQL Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering what the difference between the following queries (using two different join syntaxs) would be.  I saw this in some code I was inherited and was curious if there outcome is always the same.  And if not, why you would use one over the other.

Query #1 Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN TableB b
    INNER JOIN TableC c
      ON b.TableBId = c.TableCId
     ON b.TableBId = a.TableAId
```

Query #2 Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN TableB b
     ON b.TableBId = a.TableAId
  INNER JOIN TableC c
     ON b.TableBId = c.TableCId
```

Comment: look at the execution plan if there is any difference.

Comment: Are you sure that #1 is valid SQL. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx I cannot see how that would work.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is valid SQL. Here is the fiddle to show no execution error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b00427/1

Comment: I find query #1 confusing and not very clear - I would personally always use query #2. The results and execution plans are identical so there's no functional difference

Comment: Is query #1 the same as `INNER JOIN (TableB b INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.TableBId = c.TableCId) ON b.TableBId = a.TableAId` basically implicit `()`'s...if so that'd be really confusing if you mixed in an outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been stated, you can review the [execution plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) to verify that these are indeed the same queries. I am almost certain that they are, though

More to your question of why you would choose one over the other. I would say that this comes down to style preferences. Most of the time you will see Query #2 because it has a clearer definition for future readers. If you create a truly complicated query, then the benefit you gain grows tremendously.

I cannot really vouch for the other approach as I truly believe that it becomes too unreadable and should never be used. Again, that is my opinion and, the reasoning comes down to opinions/styles.

**However**, the standard way is query2, so I would stick with that :)...but again, just me

Comment: "standard way is query2" -- both queries conform to the SQL standard (and are semantically equivalent).

Comment: @onedaywhen Standard as in Industry Standard. Yes, both are SQL Standard, but very few devs write it in the way that query1 is written

Answer (score 0):

Try to preview the [execution plan](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/). It will very likely be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plans of your query are exactly the same.